# Как отменить disabled модального окна Bootstrap?

Tags: jquery, bootstrap

Использую Bootstrap и одну из тем https://bootswatch.com

И вот, обновили темы, теперь все модальные окна по умолчанию сделали disabled. 
Как включить enabled?

Comment: объясните подробнее, что вы имеете ввиду под словом `disabled`?

Comment: элементы недоступны... всё серым....Разобрался) У меня был бутстрап 3.3.2, а темы для 3.3.4... поставил бутстрап версии 3.3.4 - всё заработало!